# Using XPath to get multiple values from HTML

Tags: php, xpath

I want to extract multiple values from some HTML, and I feel XPath is probably the ideal way to do this.

What I was thinking of doing was looping through each `tr` that has the class `data` then within the loop getting the data I needed which is the `route_number` the text within the `a` (also in the title) and the `via` text.

The HTML is below:

```
<tr class="data"><th class="route_number"><a href="/routes/west-midlands/B001v/?tab=" title="Dudley - Sedgley - Wolverhampton - Tettenhall Wood"><span class="route_number small_curvy">1</span></a></th>
  <td class="main_and_via">
    <a href="/routes/west-midlands/B001v/?tab=" title="Dudley - Sedgley - Wolverhampton - Tettenhall Wood">Dudley - Sedgley - Wolverhampton - Tettenhall Wood</a>
            <span class="via"><strong>via</strong> Dudley Road and Tettenhall Road</span>
          </td>
</tr><tr class="data"><th class="route_number"><a href="/routes/west-midlands/B002/?tab=" title="Birmingham City Centre - Sparkbrook - Yardley Wood - Warstock / Maypole"><span class="route_number small_curvy">2</span></a></th>
  <td class="main_and_via">
    <a href="/routes/west-midlands/B002/?tab=" title="Birmingham City Centre - Sparkbrook - Yardley Wood - Warstock / Maypole">Birmingham City Centre - Sparkbrook - Yardley Wood - Warstock / Maypole</a>
            <span class="via"><strong>via</strong> Yardley Wood Road</span>
          </td>
</tr>
```

Is looping through each `tr` then having separate queries for the `route number`, `anchor text` and `via text` ideal or can it be done with a single XPath query?

Comment: wouldn't really be any different than just using getAttribute() and getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath's "context" support:

```
$tr = $xpath->query("//tr[@class='data']");

foreach($tr as $row) {
   $route = $tr->query("//td[contains(@class, 'route_number')]", $row);
   etc...
}
```

Note the `$row` in the second ->query() call. It provides the context for where the search should begin. Instead of searching the whole DOM tree, xpath will only search the particular branch that $row points at.

Doing it this way guarantees that the `.route_number` you find is the one that belongs to the $row you're dealing with, and not a .router_number from somewhere else in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

You could query all those values that you want them *if* they exist always:

```
(
    (//tr[@class = "data"])
        /*[@class="route_number"]//span
        |//tr[@class = "data"]/*[@class="main_and_via"]/a
        |//tr[@class = "data"]//*[@class="via"]
)/text()
```

Result:

```
#0: DOMText (length: 1) "1"
#1: DOMText (length: 50) "Dudley - Sedgley - Wolverhampton - Tettenhall Wood"
#2: DOMText (length: 32) " Dudley Road and Tettenhall Road"
#3: DOMText (length: 1) "2"
#4: DOMText (length: 71) "Birmingham City Centre - Sparkbrook - Yardley Wood - Warstock / Maypole"
#5: DOMText (length: 18) " Yardley Wood Road"
```

[See it in action.](http://eval.in/16207)